# copying zipfile results in being unable to expand it

Tags: python, python-2.7

in my code, I do the following with a zipfile:

```
zipped = zipfile.ZipFile('reports.zip', 'w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
for f in os.listdir(csv_path):
  zipped.write('%s/%s' % (csv_path, f))
if zipped.testzip() != None:
  raise IOError('Something was wrong with the zipfile!')
copy2('reports.zip', os.path.join(app.config['DOWNLOADS'], 'reports.zip'))
zipped.close()
```

When I uncompress it in the directory it was created in, it seems to expand plenty fine. However, when I go to the downloads folder, it says

```
Unable to expand "reports.zip" into "downloads"
Error 1 - Operation Not Permitted
```

(archive utility mac os x)

What would cause this with copying the file? How would it be effectively avoided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copied file before it was closed. Change order of two last lines.